# Why Java PrintStream have to Overload its print() functions?

Tags: java, object, overloading, printstream

Here you are: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28float%29

Just one function could serve all the purposes:

```
public void print (Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        // print "null"
    } else {
        // print o.toString();
    }
}
```

More elaborations. For example, `internal_print(String str)` is a function that write to the print stream. Then the only one function needed would be:

```
public void print (Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        internal_print( "null" );
    } else {
        internal_print( o.toString() );
    }
}
```

For other `float`, `int`, `char`, `long`, etc. overloadings, i can imagine they are just like:

```
public void print (float o) {
    if (o == null) {
        internal_print( "null" );
    } else {
        internal_print( o.toString() );
    }
}

public void print (int o) {
    if (o == null) {
        internal_print( "null" );
    } else {
        internal_print( o.toString() );
    }
}

public void print (char o) {
    if (o == null) {
        internal_print( "null" );
    } else {
        internal_print( o.toString() );
    }
}

public void print (long o) {
    if (o == null) {
        internal_print( "null" );
    } else {
        internal_print( o.toString() );
    }
}

...
```

Or even just calling the killer function `print (Object o)`.

Could you please explain. Many thanks!!

Comment: primitives cannot be `null`, and don't have `toString()`!

Comment: Ooops good spot (Y) Thats my fault and typo. But after casted into `((Object) an_int)` in function parameter, it can check null and toString().

Comment: Primitives are not objects. They cannot be used as objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historical reasons: the `PrintStream` class exists since Java 1.0, long before autoboxing was added (in 1.5).

Autoboxing is what would enable you to pass a primite type to `print(Object o)`. Without it `PrintStream` had to implement an overload for each primitive type separately.

By the way, the implementations of `print(..)` for primitive types is more like:

```
public void print (int o) {
    print(String.valueOf(o));
}
```

... and the implementation of `String.valueOf(..)` basically delegates to methods in wrapper classes, such as `Integer.toString(int)` and `Long.toString(long)`. You can read the source code at [docjar](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).

Comment: does "autoboxing" means casting `((Object) an_int)`?

Comment: Autoboxing means that primitive types such as `int` are automatically "boxed" in wrapper objects when you need to treat them like objects. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html